# How do I track the currently-touched element while the touch point moves between multiple touchable elements?

Tags: react-native, react-native-svg, panresponder

I have a UI like this:

```
<Container>
  <Box id="a" />
  <Box id="b" />
  <Box id="c" />
</Container>
<Text>You are touching: {touchedBoxId}</Text>
```

```
 ______________
|container     |
|  __  __  __  |
| |a ||b ||c | | You are touching: a
| |__||__||__| |
|______________|
```

I want to update the `You are touching: a` text when a different element is touched. Specifically, I want to support this usage:

- Press down at any point in the container with one finger
- While keeping the finger in the screen, move the finger to any box `a/b/c`
- When the finger touches `a/b/c`, update the text
- Move the finger to another box and update the text again
- Etc.

I tried adding `onPressIn` handlers to each box. This works for tapping a single box. However, if I move my finger between boxes, then the other boxes' `onPressIn` handlers are not called. In other words, I have to lift my finger before another box will observe a touch event.

I have implemented this before by adding `PanResponder` handlers to `Container` and figuring out which box is touched based on move events' coordinates. This approach is cumbersome, and I assume there is a simpler way to implement the desired behavior.

If it matters, the container is really a `react-native-svg` `Svg` element and the boxes `a/b/c` are really SVG `Rect` elements.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Using onResponderMove(event, gestureState), while touched svg element `A` and moved finger to element `B`. We can straight away handle element `A` but not `B`. In `onResponderMove`, use
`(event.nativeEvent.locationX >= B.x && event.nativeEvent.locationX <= (B.x + b.width) && event.nativeEvent.locationY >= B.y && event.nativeEvent.locationY <= (B.y + B.height))`

Do let me know if you found a better way of doing the above.
Or use PanGestureHandler from react-native-gesture-handler.